# clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am migrating from 4.3 to xCode preview45 
While linking my coreplot lib, i am getting this, which i am trying to resolve since last 5 days.

Please suggest me what should i do to overcome this issue. clang:

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I tried changing C/C++ compiler,linker flag, etc, nothing worked so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to pull the latest code with Mercurial. If you don't want to do that, you need to remove several compiler flags and make some other changes. See the necessary changes [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=aec950cf712874e991ca459d2e20ab2dc17135a6) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=13a73adc4adc5fb01d2baa367996e7e1093c9d50).

Comment: This answer fixed my problem. I ended up removing the `-lstdc++` and `-falign-loops=16` flags from the "Other C Flags" entry under the CorePlot-CocoaTouch static library.